# Adding Additional Conditions to joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I can easily join on multiple column conditions using something like this in Rails 4

```
results = Company.joins("LEFT JOIN subscriptions s ON s.company_id = companies.id AND s.end_date is null")
```

Is there another way to accomplish this without specifying the full join statement?